# Can I move a DOM node from an iFrame to parent's body?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Currently I'm trying to move a DOM node by using the following snippet:

```
var element = document.getElementById('my-id');
parent.window.body.appendChild(element);
```

The code above is rendered within an iFrame, but I'm getting the exception "parent.window.body is undefined". Is this a security feature (since I effectively do want to break out of the iframe)?

Please note: **I do not want to re-ask "how to move a DOM node" per se**, but to move it across borders of an iframe!

Comment: Can you move a DOM node from a browser tab to another browser tab?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu: It's unclear from your comment whether you're suggesting you can or cannot; you can.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You can move an element from one tab to another if you own both windows and if they are on the same url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, within the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). (Checked on Firefox, Chrome, IE8, IE11, and Edge.) Note that when you do so, any event listeners attached to it remain attached, which could be confusing. Also note that the old [DOM3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) allowed for an error if the node was being appended to a different document, but the more recent WHAT-WG DOM spec doesn't mention doing that (if you start at [`appendChild`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-appendchild) and follow through, you end up [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-ensure-pre-insertion-validity), which doesn't have that exception listed).

But `body` isn't a property of the window, it's a property of the `document`. Also note that `parent.window` is redundant. So:

```
parent.document.body.appendChild(element);
// ----^
```

Comment: I know that it will work, and that you can create strange results by this, because it will also move the event listeners/code from the other window. But is is valid according to the specs? I can only find `WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: Raised if newChild was created from a different document than the one that created this node.` so to me the specs say it should not be possible.

Comment: Whoa, what a likely typo! Thank you very much!

Comment: @t.niese: The old DOM3 spec had that, the current WHAT-WG spec doesn't. I've updated the answer to call that out, and to mention potentially-confusing things like event handlers, thanks. :-)

Comment: Interesting, but I don't know if I should like the idea that the browser vendors agreed on that. Moving elements between documents open up completely new possibilities of memory leaks e.g. if the closure of an event listener keeps the old document or console alive.

Comment: @t.niese: It does indeed. :-) I think I'd generally be tempted to use `cloneNode` or even take a trip through markup instead.